# Export comments from a PowerPoint presentation in a table of a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, comments, powerpoint, extract

My intention is to use a VBA code to extract the comments from a PowerPoint document and paste the information in a table in Word.

I started to build a code that works on Word and I tried to adapt in to work with PowerPoint. Unfortunately I run in some errors like Error 07 memory issue, while the code works perfectly to extract comments form a word document...

I am lost and do not know what to do...

Is there an expert who could help me verifying the code? I made notes in the code to make it easy to read.

PS: In PowerPoint VBA Editor, I did enabled the reference for Word.

```
Sub Tansfer_PPT_comments_in_WordDoc()

Dim n As Long
Dim nCount As Long
Dim ppt As Presentation
Dim wdapp As Word.Application
Dim wddoc As Word.Document
Dim wdtable As Table

Set ppt = ActivePresentation
nCount = ActivePresentation.Comments.Count

'Open a Word document
On Error Resume Next

Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Word isn't already running
    Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Create word page with landscape orientation
Set wddoc = Documents.Add
    wddoc.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

'Insert a 5-column table
With wddoc
    .Content = ""
    Set wdtable = .Tables.Add _
        (Range:=Selection.Range, _
        Numrows:=nCount + 1, _
        NumColumns:=5)
End With

'DOCUMENT FORMATTING

'Define Normal and Header style
With wddoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
End With

With wddoc.Styles(wdStyleHeader)
    .Font.Size = 8
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
End With

'Format table
With wdtable
    .Range.Style = wdStyleNormal
    .AllowAutoFit = False
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    .PreferredWidth = 100
    .Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 2
    .Columns(2).PreferredWidth = 20
    .Columns(3).PreferredWidth = 40
    .Columns(4).PreferredWidth = 8
    .Columns(5).PreferredWidth = 40
    .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True

    .Columns(1).Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

    .Rows(1).Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
        Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
        Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603937025
    End With

'Add table borders
With wdtable.Borders
    .InsideLineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
    .InsideLineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
    .InsideColor = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    .OutsideLineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
    .OutsideLineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
    .OutsideColor = Options.DefaultBorderColor
End With

'DOCUMENT CONTENT

'Define table headings names
With wdtable.Rows(1)
    .Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Cells(1).Range.Text = "Page"
    .Cells(2).Range.Text = "Comment scope"
    .Cells(3).Range.Text = "Comment text"
    .Cells(4).Range.Text = "Author"
    .Cells(5).Range.Text = "Parexel response"
End With

'Insert information from the comments in ppt into the wddoc table
For n = 1 To nCount
    With wdtable.Rows(n + 1)
        'Page number
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = _
        ppt.Comments(n).Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        'The text marked by the comment
        .Cells(2).Range.Text = ppt.Comments(n).Scope
        'The comment itself
        .Cells(3).Range.Text = ppt.Comments(n).Range.Text
        'The comment author
        .Cells(4).Range.Text = ppt.Comments(n).Author
    End With
Next n

ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenRefresh

wddoc.Activate

Set ppt = Nothing
Set wddoc = Nothing
Set wdtable = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will fail at:

```
ActivePresentation.Comments.Count
```

since Comments are not a Presentation property. And, once you get over that hurdle, your code will fail at:

```
.Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

since PowerPoint Comments don't have a scope property and, even if they did, '.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)' refers to a Word constant, not a PowerPoint one.

You can't simply take VBA methods, properties, and constants that apply to one application and assume they apply to another in the same way. You need to develop your PowerPoint code using valid PowerPoint methods, properties, and constants.

For some code to get you started on the right tack, see: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00900_Export_comments_to_a_text_file_-PowerPoint_2002_and_later-.htm

Comment: Thank you for the note and the website.

Would you know where to find a page that would highlight the different between Excel PowerPoint and Words commands as well as giving equivalents between applications?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such site.

Comment: Okay, I found a piece of code on the forum which is meant to extract the comments in an excel file. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616989/export-powerpoint-comments-to-excel

The code work perfectly at the exception that it does not copy the replies to a comments. Do you have any idea of what command to use for that?